# Xcode: Storyboard using right aligned "x" position

Tags: xcode, storyboard

My Storyboard got crazy! Every element frame has the x position aligned for the right.

For example:

- normal: 127x, 0y, 180w, 70h
- mine: 307x (right border), 0y, 180w, 70h

Any idea? Probably it's a configuration but I can't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the upper-left control point  as the origin reference in the size inspector

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks man!
I will accept your answer after 10 minutes (minimum time).

Comment: You're welcome! Also note that this is a handy tool for resizing too (the resize will happen with the selected point as anchor)